# Is Gran Torino faster than One for All 30%?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In My Hero Academia season 6th episode 6th,

> Gran Torino grabs Midoriya and Bakugo who are both flying at One For All 30% speed and takes them away from Shigaraki

Does this mean Gran Torino is faster than One for All 30%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is implied that Gran Torino is faster than One for All 30% because it is said that when Izuku will reach 100%, his speed is set surpass Gran Torino.

Warning: Spoilers as the events are ongoing

> **At 100% his speed rises** to levels rivaling or even surpassing that of All Might, which allows him to casually blitz capable villains and move several times faster than the eye can see. During his fight with Overhaul, he could completely out-speed the villain and move fast enough to create afterimages, and later completely overwhelm him with an instantaneous rush of punches. When fighting against Tomura Shigaraki, he could effortlessly blitz the villain and severely damage his weakened body, **despite him possessing speed rivaling that of All Might and outclassing that of Gran Torino.**

From: [Izuku Midoriya - Fandom Wiki](https://myheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Izuku_Midoriya)